# How to store specific options for node.js CLI tool?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, command-line-interface, config

I'm looking for a good practice there. I need to store some global config options in my node.js command-line tool.

For example typing in bash:

```
$: mycommand set myGlobalOption=value
```

and then I can use `myGlobalOption` with another commands, is storing this value in environment variable a good solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store this in a configuration file in the user's home directory like `~/.myprog.json`. You can't store persistent data in environment variables because those ultimately come from shell configuration files like `~/.bash_profile` which are not machine editable. Allowing these values to be set by environment variables is reasonable, but just have the user set them herself and don't bother trying to have a `set` command like you describe.

You could also just take these options as command line arguments like `mycommand --myglobaloption=value` and let users who want to always use the same value set up a shell alias like `alias mc="mycommand --myglobaloption=value"`.